# is it possible to write system level code in vala

Tags: operating-system, driver, kernel, vala

Is it possible to write system level source code in Vala.
like for a small Micro kernel OS?
or for use it in the Linux kernel for modules or device drivers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, yes, but in reality it's probably not very practical.

People have written kernel modules in Vala before, but AFAIK nothing really serious. Actually, someone wrote a [Multiboot kernel using Vala](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/vala-list/2009-February/msg00032.html) a few years ago.

You can get around the dependency on GLib by using the posix profile (pass --profile posix), but it tends to be a bit buggy and lots of features aren't supported, including a lot of the stuff that makes programming in Vala a pleasant experience.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. [Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala) is tied to the *GObject* and [Glib](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/chapter-gtype.html) *gtype* type system (inside GTK) - including its [reference count based memory management](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-memory.html). The Linux kernel uses a different (even if conceptually similar) memory management. And inside your microkernel OS, you need to provide one.

Comment: A few corrections. As I stated below, you can get around GLib (including GObject) by using the posix profile. Also, Vala can be used without reference counting (lots of bindings for non-reference counted code exist, including bindings for POSIX and the Linux kernel). Also, glib isn't "inside GTK"... GTK+ depends on GLib, and their communities are close, but GLib (and GObject and GIO) are not tied to GTK+. For example, Clutter is a competing UI toolkit which is based on GLib/GObject but does not depend on GTK+.

Comment: It depends what you call Gtk, for me it the set of software distributed on gtk.org (so contains libglib, libatk, libpango, libgtk...)

Answer (score 1):

Some update to the answers above: the posix profile has been deleted from vala codebase in version 0.17.4, because it was unmaintained. [Here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/vala-list/2012-August/msg00018.html) is the announcement.